# Почему "==0" так влияет на код?

Tags: c++, c

Скорее всего здесь нужно включить логику, но поверьте, сколько бы я не пытался так и не смог понять почему код под номером "1" выводит только результат деления на число без остатка, а код под номером "2" выводит только числа которые делятся на число без остатка? можно посмотреть и понять что это из-за функции "if", в котором условия(или параметры) отличаются. Но неужели это из-за этого отличия " == 0 "? Если это так, то почему это так работает? Я не могу понять, заранее спасибо за ответ.

КОД ПОД НОМЕРОМ "1":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespase std;

int main(){
   int num = 1;
   while(num <= 50){
   if (num % 3){
     cout << num << endl;
   }
     num += 1;
 }
return 0;
}
```

КОД ПОД НОМЕРОМ "2":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespase std;

int main(){
   int num = 1;
   while(num <= 50){
   if (num % 3 == 0){
     cout << num << endl;
   }
     num += 1;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в курсе вообще, что означает это ==0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Условие `if (num % 3)` означает `if ((num % 3) != 0)`
Если остаток от деления **не равен** нулю, то выполняется первая ветвь if-a, а если равен, то вторая.

Условие `if (num % 3 ==0)` означает:
Если остаток от деления **равен** нулю, то выполняется первая ветвь if-a, а если не равен, то вторая.

Так что же удивительного в том, что противоположные условия дают противоположные результаты?

По вопросу из комментария - оператор if работает согласно народному творчеству

> "Деньги есть - Уфа гуляем, денег нет - Чишма сидим."

Если условие выполняется, т.е. выражение в скобках после `if` равно `True` то работает первая ветвь после `if`, если нет (выражение в скобках после `if` равно `False` или нулю (во многих языках)), то работает ветвь `else` (если она присутствует)

Comment: Я кажется понял. Автор вопроса считает, что % проверяет делимость и возвращает bool. Тогда его непонимание очевидно.

Comment: В первом случае выдаются числа 1 2 4 5 7..., т.е числа, которые не делятся на 3

Comment: Все спасибо, я понял что мы сравниваем полученный остаток от деления а не его результат, все встало на свои места. Я думал что мы сравниваем именно его результат деления

Comment: @KoVadim А, вот в чём причина...

Comment: @Абдурахман Но тут ведь операция же взятия остатка от деления, а не самого деления. Но так то всё бывает )